# Add Multiple Repositories in a Team - Bonobo Git Server

Tags: git, automation, repository, bonobo

We are using bonobo git server in our company. I want all the team members to be able to access all the existing repositories but don't want them to add as administrator.I am looking for all the possible ways. As manually adding them is not a option , as there are 100+ repositories.

Below are the two options I can think of but don't have a idea how to execute them. If anyone has idea please help.

Option 1. Create a team , add all the members to that team and then add this team to all the repositories. But the issue is I can't manually add the team to all the repositories. So is there a way that I can do this in one go ?

Option 2. Can i create a bash script and do this by changing some config ?

Also i was just curious where is all the information stores (Contributors and team for repositories )

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teams sound like the right approach.

If you're not using Active Directory then Bonobo will be storing all the permissions in a SQLite database - you may be able to hack on that with one of the various SQLite manipulation tools that exist.